# Is there any formula for the sum of the numbers from $n=a$ to $n=b$ of $ k^n?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there an algebraic formula for the sum $\sum_{n=a}^b k^{n}$ for a real $k$? Specifically, is there a formula using a constant number of those operations: addition, multiplication, division, modulus, subtraction and exponentiation?

Comment: @bof oh, that is obvious. I feel silly now. Thanks.

Comment: @bof I actually can use exponentiation. I just noticed I forgot including it. What a mess. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $S$ is the sum, then

$$\begin{align}S&=k^a+k^{a+1}+\dots+k^{b-1}+k^b\\-(\ \ kS&=\phantom{k^a}\ \ \ \ \ k^{a+1}+\dots+k^{b-1}+k^b+k^{b+1}\ \ )\\\hline(1-k)S&=k^a\phantom{+k^{a+1}+\dots+k^{b-1}+k^b}\ \ -k^{b+1}\end{align}$$

So it is clear that

$$S=\frac{k^a-k^{b+1}}{1-k}$$

Comment: Can't believe I asked that. In my defense I'm really tired... thanks!

Comment: @MaiaVictor glad I could clear that up!